# How to calculate when position(x,y,z) of a css2DObject is off camera view in threejs

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, 3d

I have an SVG logo rendered with css2DObject positioned to coordinate x,y,z on a 3D rotating map rendered with webgl.

css2DObject does not rotate in 3D perspective so i want to auto hide (i.e opacity:0) css2dobject whenever it's position(x,y,z) on the map is no more in camera view.

I do not want to use Textureloader because it reduces the quality of my image.

I want the simulation similar to the way the labels auto hide here https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/mercury-0930a4f0405243f6a9f93a4da79c66b6.

below is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/scripts/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/CSS2DRenderer.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@seregpie/three.text-texture"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@seregpie/three.text-sprite"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="earthmodel" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; "></div>
  <div id="earthmodel2" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>

  <script>
    var scene;

    var sites = [{
      name: "facebook",
      lat: 37.484557,
      long: -122.147845,
      url: "resources/logo-airbnb.svg"
    }];


    function init() {
      var onRenderFcts = [];
      scene = new THREE.Scene();
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
      var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, 1, 0.2, 1000);
      camera.position.z = -2;

      const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, autoSize: true });
      renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
      renderer.setSize(500, 500);
      const earthDom = document.getElementById('earthmodel');
      earthDom.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


      var labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
      labelRenderer.setSize(500, 500);
      labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
      labelRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = "0";
      labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
      const earthDom2 = document.getElementById('earthmodel2');

      earthDom2.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

      const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, labelRenderer.domElement);
      controls.enableDamping = true;
      controls.campingFactor = 0.25;
      controls.enableZoom = false;

      var alight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x888888);
      scene.add(alight);

      var dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xcccccc, 1);
      dlight.position.set(20, 2, 2);
      scene.add(dlight);

      var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);
      var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

      var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      scene.add(earthMesh);
      material.map = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(
        'resources/land_color.jpg'
      );

      var css2dObj,coord;

      sites.map((val) => {

        //Create dot for each site
        var siteImage = document.createElement("img");
        siteImage.className = "logo_dot";
        siteImage.setAttribute("id", val.name);
        siteImage.setAttribute("alt", val.name);
        siteImage.setAttribute("src", val.url);

        css2dObj = new THREE.CSS2DObject(siteImage);

        siteImage.parent = css2dObj;
        siteImage.style.cursor = "pointer";
        siteImage.style.position = "relative";
        siteImage.style.zIndex = "-1";
        siteImage.style.width = "80px";
        coord= placeObjectOnPlanet(css2dObj, val.lat, val.long, 0.5);
        group.add(css2dObj)
      })


      earthDom.addEventListener(
        'mousemove',
        function (event) {
          earthMesh.rotation.y += event.movementX * 0.002;
          earthMesh.rotation.x -= event.movementY * 0.002;

          group.rotation.y += event.movementX * 0.002;
          group.rotation.x -= event.movementY * 0.002;
        },
        false
      );




      requestAnimationFrame(function animate(nowMsec) {
        // keep looping
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update();

        earthMesh.rotation.y += 0.004;
        group.rotation.y += 0.004;

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
      });
    }


    function placeObjectOnPlanet(object, lat, lon, radius) {
      var latRad = lat * (Math.PI / 180);
      var lonRad = -lon * (Math.PI / 180);
      var x = Math.cos(latRad) * Math.cos(lonRad) * radius;
      var y = Math.cos(latRad) * radius;
      var z = Math.cos(latRad) * Math.sin(lonRad) * radius;
      object.position.set(x, y, z);
      // object.scale.set(1, 0.1, 0.1);
      return { x, y, z }
    }

    init();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but [this article](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-align-html-elements-to-3d.html) might lead to one

Comment: May God Bless you man. This is exactly what i want.

Comment: @gman now i'm faced with one last issue. I want the globe and the labels to auto rotate with the implementation in the link you provided. How do i archive that?

i can get the globe to auto-rotate using  earthMesh.rotation.y += 0.004; but the label doesn't rotate.

Comment: Found out all i needed to do was set controls.autorotate=true on OrbitControls